# Add border to clipped image in chrome

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to trace a white 1px crisp border to a clipped image?

I tried using border, outline but these are not placed according to the clipping. 
I also tried faking a border using a second shadow:

```
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,1)) ;
```

but result is not as good as expected.. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k75AE/2/)

Works on chrome/webkit only, but that's ok.

Comment: i think jsfiddle.net is down atm.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like this it'll work:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(255,255,255,1); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(255,255,255,1);
```

Comment: I don't mean to have a larger border, just a 1px crisp border actually, but thanks!